# Better way to initialise std::array item that has non-default constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, stdarray

Currently when initialising the **basicEnemies array** I need to pass in the **audioManager** to the constructor of each **basicEnemy** class. However, I have **20** basic enemies so is there a better way to initialise each basicEnemy from the **MainGameScene** without having to repeat the audioManager pass to constructor the way I am doing it? The constructor for each **basicEnemy** needs to be called.

```
MainGameScene.h
MainGameScene(AudioManager *audioManager)
std::array<BasicEnemy, 20> basicEnemies;
```

```
MainGameScene.cpp
MainGameScene::MainGameScene(AudioManager *audioManager) : basicEnemies{audioManager, audioManager, audioManager, audioManager...}
{
}
```

```
BasicEnemy.h
BasicEnemy(AudioManager *audioManager)
```

If its not too much to ask what is the ':' part after the MainGameScene constructor called or what is it referred to as so I can ask more precisely next time?

Comment: "*what is the ':' part*" - it's called [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). For you actual question - are you sure that array is the right data structure? Do you always have exactly 20 enemies alive? Perhaps `std::vector` would be more suiting?

Comment: Possible options: 1) Use `std::vector`, `std::array` seems odd here anyways 2) Store `std::unique_ptr<BasicEnemy>` instead 3) Make `BasicEnemy` default constructable

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes, there are always 20 enemies alive and this will never change which is why array was chosen

Comment: By definition, std::array calls the default constructor of all objects. What about using a vector of BasicEnemy if you do not want this? Alternatively, you can adapt the default constructor.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann 1) the basicEnemies never changes size so array is the correct one to go with? 2) would you be able to expand on this std::unique_ptr further and how it would work with my current setup please? 3) I would like to know how to do this without the constructor being default if I ever come across this again in a different scenario

Comment: @user12322186 whatever works for you. but `std::array` seems like a odd choice anyways: e.g consider what happens when that requirement changes in the future and enemies are loaded dynamically from a config file? `std::vector` is the goto choice for collections and any other structure without a solid reason will raise some eyebrows for sure. Notice that you pratically gain nothing here by using `std::array`. Regarding `std::unique_ptr`: See Evg answer and replace `std::optional` by `std::unique_ptr`, same idea, slightly different implementation.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on `std::array<BasicEnemy>` data member, you can use additional level of indirection and `std::index_sequence`:

```
class MainGameScene {
private:
    static constexpr std::size_t n_enemies = 20;
    std::array<BasicEnemy, n_enemies> basicEnemies;

    template<std::size_t... is>
    MainGameScene(AudioManager* audioManager, std::index_sequence<is...>) :
        basicEnemies{(is, audioManager)...}
    {}

public:
    MainGameScene(AudioManager* audioManager) : 
        MainGameScene(audioManager, std::make_index_sequence<n_enemies>{})
    {}
};
```

If you can relax the requirement on the data member type, along with `std::shared_ptr` (which allocates on heap), another option is `std::optional` (which stores an object inside itself):

```
class MainGameScene {
private:
    std::array<std::optional<BasicEnemy>, 20> basicEnemies;

public:
    MainGameScene(AudioManager* audioManager) {
        std::fill(basicEnemies.begin(), basicEnemies.end(), audioManager);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may generate them:

```
MainGameScene::MainGameScene(AudioManager *audioManager) 
{
    std::generate(basicEnemies.begin(), basicEnemies.end(), [&audioManager]() {
         return BasicEnemy(audioManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's under assumption that `BasicEnemy` has a default constructor.

Comment: Moreover, the constructor of each `BasicEnemy` are still being called (before the generate) with this strategy (although this is now implicit).

Comment: I belive `std::array` implies default constructor for container type or aggregate initialization, either way, the array already comes filled with elements;

Answer (score 0):

Add a default value for the parameter, which calls a global factory function:

```
 BasicEnemy(AudioManager *audioManager = getAudioManager() )
```